# Cannot modify http accept header in SOAP WebService client - JAX-WS 2.2.10 - JDK1.7

Tags: java, http-headers, jax-ws, webservice-client

I migrated a webservice client from jdk1.6 jax-ws (v1 ? An old one - 2005) to jdk1.7 jax-ws 2.2.10. 
The old one was functional, but I have a problem with the new one :
The service (from another society, php server) responds to me : http 406 error, not acceptable.

The accept header I send is :

```
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

With the old version, I had :

```
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
```

So I tried to modify the http header like this (inside a new handler in my binding handler chain):

In my client :

```
    javax.xml.ws.Binding binding = ((BindingProvider) ServiceXXX).getBinding();
    List<Handler> hchain = binding.getHandlerChain();
    if (hchain == null) {hchain = new ArrayList<Handler>();}
    hchain.add(new HTTPUserAgentHandler());
    binding.setHandlerChain(hchain);
```

In my new handler :

```
Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
if (null == headers) {headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();}
headers.put("Accept", Arrays.asList("text/xml", "multipart/related", "*/*"));
context.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

My http header is now correct but in HttpTransportPipe class, it's overwritten :

```
        reqHeaders.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList(ct.getContentType()));
        if (ct.getAcceptHeader() != null) {
            reqHeaders.put("Accept", Collections.singletonList(ct.getAcceptHeader()));
        }
        if (binding instanceof SOAPBinding) {
            writeSOAPAction(reqHeaders, ct.getSOAPActionHeader());
        }
```

The server, apparently 1.1, needs I send an accept with `"*/*"`
Any Idea of how I can do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a way, it's not the perfect solution ... (If someone has better ..)
So :
I added a file named `com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory` in `./src/META-INF/services` in which there is:

```
com.YYY.XXX.MonHttpTransportTubeFactory
```

I added this class:

```
package com.YYY.XXX;

import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ClientTubeAssemblerContext;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Tube;
import com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe;

public class MonHttpTransportTubeFactory extends TransportTubeFactory{

    @Override
    public Tube doCreate(ClientTubeAssemblerContext context) {
        context.setCodec(new MonSOAPBindingCodec(context.getBinding().getFeatures()));
        return new HttpTransportPipe(context.getCodec(), context.getBinding());
    }
}
```

and this one : (copy of existing `SOAPBidingCodec` jaxws-ri src) :

```
public class MonSOAPBindingCodec extends MonMimeCodec implements com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.SOAPBindingCodec {
...
    public MonSOAPBindingCodec(WSFeatureList features, StreamSOAPCodec xmlSoapCodec) {
        super(getSoapVersion(features), features);

        this.xmlSoapCodec = xmlSoapCodec;
        xmlMimeType = xmlSoapCodec.getMimeType();

        String clientAcceptedContentTypes = xmlSoapCodec.getMimeType() + ", */*";

        WebServiceFeature fi = features.get(FastInfosetFeature.class);
...
```

So the service call my `HttpTransportTubeFactory` and includes my custom SOAP codec.

It's not very beautiful, but it works ..